# Submit multiple input fields which have the same 'name' attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting a form to work, where-by there are multiple input fields (text) that have the same name attribute.

On the backend, I'm using node.js and Mongoose, using a POST method. Here is a sample of the code:

```
if(existingFruit) {
        Fruit.findOneAndUpdate({fruit: req.body.fruit}, {
            $push: { price: req.body.price }},
```

Here is the input field in question:

```
<label for="price">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>
```

Basically, somewhere else on the form a user will enter the name of a fruit. Then on the backend, the code looks through the database to see if that fruit is in the DB. If it is (existingFruit), a function is performed. This function will take the **price** a user entered, and add it to the DB as an array.

This form works fine. The price will be entered into the DB in an array (which is set up in my schema, not shown here for simplicity).

Now, notice the 'name' attribute, which is equal to *price*. Suppose I do this to my form:

```
<label for="price1">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price1"/>

<label for="price2">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price2"/>
```

Now my form lets users enter 2 prices for the fruit. Both have the same **name** attributes of **price**. This form won't submit; it will always give me an error.

I don't know how/where to fix this problem.

Comment: It's not standard to use same id or name for different elements, why don't you use different names for elements?

Comment: That was a mistake, my fault. I changed the ID's. Even with different ID's, my problem remains.

Comment: change the name as well

Answer (score 0):

You should make a json object for each of your record and send an array of your objects to the backend.. And access it as you want in node.js

Or if its an array with single dimension, you can generate an array directly as

Something like

```
var myPrices = [];
function createArray() {
    $("input[name=price]").each(function() {

        var price = $(this).val();

        myPrices.push(price);
    });

    console.log(myPrices);
    return myPrices
}
```

And yes, It is a **bad practice** to use the same name and id for multiple input fields.

A better approach will be that,

You will have a pair of  in one row. Keep one button to add such rows dynamically.

In the end, when the user is done, make a json object of each row as

```
{
    name: 'FRUITNAME',
    price : 'PRICEOFFRUIT'
}
```

create an array of such objects and then send it to server side.

Comment: Regarding the issue of using the same name for multiple input fields: Users have a +/- button where they can add/remove price fields. If they have a bunch of prices to input, they can use the + button to allow more input fields to appears. If the names on each input field is unique, my backend code wouldn't be able to reach the additional input fields (because on the backend, the code says to look for a name field labeled 'price').

Comment: ya so can you not simply send a json object with 'price' as the key and the price array as value of the key on the backend?

Comment: Hm, interesting. I am going to try what you've suggested (turning the inputs into a JSON object) and get back to you.

Comment: Sure @MonkeyOnARock I will be waiting.